# Remove Entities from Room DB

Tags: android, android-room

Fairly new to room and having a hard time finding info on this.  Currently we define our database like this:

```
@Database(entities = {TwcLocation.class,
        CurrentObservation.class,
        Day.class,
        Hour.class,
        Station.class,
        StationCurrentObservation.class}, version = 1, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class TwcLocationDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
```

Now, we want to remove a bunch of unused entities so it looks like this:

```
@Database(entities = {TwcLocation.class, Tag.class}, version = 1)
@TypeConverters({TwcLocationTypeConverter.class})
public abstract class NbcRoomDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
```

Question:  How do I do this migration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to increment the version (so it will become `version = 2`).

Next, when building the Room instance by using the `Room.databaseBuilder` method, add the `addMigration()` line.

As migration, pass it the following to remove the tables:

```
// Migration from version 1 to 2
static final Migration MIGRATION_1_2 = new Migration(1, 2) {
    @Override
    public void migrate(SupportSQLiteDatabase database) {
        // Remove the table
        database.execSQL("DROP TABLE day"); // This line for each table that you want to remove
    }
};
```

Later on you might need multiple different migrations, you can do so by using the `addMigrations()` method:

```
Room.databaseBuilder(..., ..., ...)
    .addMigrations(MIGRATION_1_2, MIGRATION_2_3)
    .build()
```

Answer (score 0):

Other option is to use [fallbackToDestructiveMigration](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RoomDatabase.Builder.html#fallbackToDestructiveMigration()) and increment database version. In such case you will not have to provide migrations. However it will clear data in all old tables.